# Fullscreen Restarts Ubuntu 18.04 if using two displays

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, fullscreen

Recently went from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and YouTube and games in fullscreen were working just fine. The problem happens when using two screens (notebook + monitor), when I try to fullscreen there is a visual glitch, then, I go back to lock screen, type password and the system has restarted.

Edit: Workspaces to Dock was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the video out is using a different display driver/hardware compared to the built in mointor. Check the syslog and dmesg to see if you can get any good hints of where the system is having and issue, is this a surface or laptop?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Workspaces to Dock Gnome extension, disabling it solved the problem.